# React Navigation: Use Tab Navigator with hidden screens

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to have 4 tabs in my app. But the app itself should have more pages that are not reachable with tabs. One thing I have tried is using nested Stack Navigators in Each Tab, but then it get's complicated when navigating from one nested Stack navigator to another nested Stack navigator (The biggest problem is goBack() not working correctly). One way to fix this would be to add Screens that can be accessed from 2 tabs to both Stack navigators of each tab, but is that the right approach? Is there another way to add "Hidden" screens to a tab navigator?

- TabA
- TabB
- - StackA
- - StackB
- TabC

When I navigate from TabC to TabB/ScreenB and then use goBack(), I get redirected to TabA. Why is that? Another problem is that when I then try to go back to TabB it automatically shows me StackB and not StackA, which should be the default.